# Importing a Swift file into another which are in different directories

Tags: swift

I am new to swift and I want to use a function which in a.swift in b.swift. a.swift, b.swift are in directory dir1 & dir2. dir1 & dir2 are in same directory.

Comment: show your coding please

Answer (score -2):

If you are doing it in iOS project then there is no need to import class/struct from other file which is inside any subdirectory inside project root directory . They are automatic available to use .